# ASP.NET user control and grid view

Tags: asp.net

IN dot net, User control has a drop down when it is changed. The grid needs to be changed, but the grid is not inside user control?

How can we achieve it?

Comment: You can use [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You bind an event using the OnSelectedIndexChange to your drop down list on your aspx page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGridType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGridType_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" >
```

Then on your C# code behind:

```
protected void ddlRunType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtblDataSource = New DataTable();
    string gridType = ddlGridType.SelectedValue;

    //remove the old data from the grid view
    TheGridView.DataSource = null;
    TheGridView.DataBind();

    //get the new data using whatever method you use to get the data
    dtblDataSource = theGridView_GetDataSource(gridType);

    //bind the new data to the list
    TheGridView.DataSource = dtblDataSource;
    TheGridView.DataBind();
}
```